# Finding winner of the competition with give minimum probability by giving method that can carry out each game of the competition

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

I came across the following problem:

> Consider a competition in which a game is played between two participants. There are total $n$ participants. Let $p_{ij}$ represent participant $i$ will beat participant $j$. Let $w_i$ represent the probability that $i$ will defeat an opponent picked uniformly at random: $$w_i=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j\neq i}p_{ij}$$ The winner of the competition is $\text{argmax}_iw_i $
> Find method that can conduct games and stop to declare winner of the competition correctly with probability at least $1-\delta$ for given $\delta\in [0,1]$

Can we frame this problem as subset selection in stochastic multi armed bandit with subset being 1? Is there any other bandit related formulation possible?